# Convert name and Value to column and rows during Export to CSV in Powershell

Tags: excel, api, powershell, nested, export

I am trying to convert name and values returned from my API call into column and rows during export but so far I have no luck.

```
$searchResponse =  Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $searchUri -ContentType application/json -Header $requestHeader  -Body $searchResultsRequest

$lists =  $searchResponse.businessO.fields | Select name, value
```

The $list returns:

```
name            value
----             ----
Name           YY
Address        ABC street
City           Seattle
Zip            01256
Name           XYZ
Address        XYZ street
City           XYZ 
Zip            45456
Name           Mike
Address        1256 Street   
City           New York
Zip            78965
```

I want to output this result as following in CSV:

```
Name     Address     City         Zip 
YY       ABC street  Seattle     01256
.
.
.
```

I tried looping through list and applied condition to check name and populate value based on it, but i end up getting either duplicates or all my output data are out of sysnc meaning Mike gets Address of YY and so on....

```
If($lists.count -ge 0){
    ForEach($list in $lists){
         if($list.name -eq "Name")      {$name= $list.value }
}
```

I would really appreciate any help on this one. Thank You.

$searchResponse results
$searchResponse |ConvertTo-Json

```
{
    "businessObjects":  [
                            {
                                "busObId":  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                "busObPublicId":  "abc345",
                                "busObRecId":  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                "fields":  "       ",
                                "links":  "",
                                "errorCode":  null,
                                "errorMessage":  null,
                                "hasError":  false
                            },
                            {
                                "busObId":  "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                "busObPublicId":  "rty567",
                                "busObRecId":  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                "fields":  "       ",
                                "links":  "",
                                "errorCode":  null,
                                "errorMessage":  null,
                                "hasError":  false
                            }
                        ],
    "hasPrompts":  false,
    "links":  [

              ],
    "prompts":  [

                ],
    "searchResultsFields":  [

                            ],
    "totalRows":  2500
}
```

Fields has the name and value which I want to output.
$searchResponse.businessObjects.fields |ConvertTo-Json

```
[
    {
        "dirty":  false,
        "displayName":  "Name",
        "fieldId":  "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "html":  null,
        "name":  "Name",
        "value":  "Mike"
    },
    {
        "dirty":  false,
        "displayName":  "Address",
        "fieldId":  "456451212113132",
        "html":  null,
        "name":  "Address",
        "value":  "Seattle"
    },
```

and so on.

Comment: what are `$lists.GetType()` and `$lists[0].GetType()`?

Comment: IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                                                                  
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object

Comment: Sorry, the formatting is little mixed up. The first one is Object[] and the later one is PSCustomObject.

Comment: Do a $lists[0] | gm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer as a teaching exercise with the expectation, one will walk through the code in the VSCode or ISE debugger and learn more about the objects, members, and more.

There are a few ways to solve this.  In this answer, I try to break down the steps in a way newer PowerShell user may learn more about the language.

```
# mock your data
$list1 = @(
[pscustomobject]@{Name='YY'},
[pscustomobject]@{Address='ABC street'},
[pscustomobject]@{City='Seattle'},
[pscustomobject]@{Zip='01256'},
[pscustomobject]@{Name='XYZ'},
[pscustomobject]@{Address='XYZ street'},
[pscustomobject]@{City='XYZ'},
[pscustomobject]@{Zip='45456'},
[pscustomobject]@{Name='Mike'},
[pscustomobject]@{Address='1256 Street'},
[pscustomobject]@{City='New York'},
[pscustomobject]@{Zip='78965'}
)

# mock your data
$list2 = @(
@{Name='YY'},
@{Address='ABC street'},
@{City='Seattle'},
@{Zip='01256'},
@{Name='XYZ'},
@{Address='XYZ street'},
@{City='XYZ'},
@{Zip='45456'},
@{Name='Mike'},
@{Address='1256 Street'},
@{City='New York'},
@{Zip='78965'}
)

# debuggng...
#$list1
#$list1.GetType()
#$list1[0].GetType()

#$list2
#$list2.GetType()
#$list2[0].GetType()

# seems your data looks like list1

$data = @()
$entry = [ordered]@{}

# transform the data into separate objects based on the field you want
foreach ($item in $list)
{
    if ($item.Name) {$entry.Name = $item.Name}
    elseif ($item.Address) {$entry.Address = $item.Address}
    elseif ($item.City) {$entry.City = $item.City}
    elseif ($item.Zip) {$entry.Zip = $item.Zip; $data += $entry; $entry = [ordered]@{}}
}

# data transformed now into an array of hashtables
# there are a few says to save as csv, one is to just roll your own rather
# than GetEnumerator(), etc.

$out = @()
$out += $data[0].Keys -join ', '
$out += $data | % {
    #$_['Name']+','+$_['Address']+','+$_['City']+','+$_['Zip']
    # or
    #$_.Name+','+$_.Address+','+$_.City+','+$_.Zip
    # or 
    $_.Name,$_.Address,$_.City,$_.Zip -join ', '

}

$out

# save $out to a file, uncomment to use after editing path
#$out | Out-File -FilePath 'c:\mycsvfile.csv'
```